# Why are the hit boxes and collisions not working correctly in my Pong game?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having two issues I need help fixing. One is when the Pong ball hits the middle of the left or right side - it twitches violently until the paddle moves over it. What it should do is, instead of violently twitching, it should bounce outwards and away from the wall.

The second issue relates to the hit box of the paddles. Right now, if the Pong ball hits the middle of the paddles it behaves as expected, but if it hits the top edge or bottom edge, it lets the ball phase through.

I was wondering if someone could help me determine why these issues are happening, and what could be done to correct them.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from math import *
##MAIN GAME PART##
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window,width=400,height=400)
canvas.pack()
sideX = -1
sideY = 0
##FUNCTIONS##
def movePaddles(event):
    key=event.keysym
    if key == 'Up':
         canvas.move(PaddleTwo,0,-10)
    elif key == 'Down':
        canvas.move(PaddleTwo,0,10)
    if key == 'w':
        canvas.move(PaddleOne,0,-10)
    elif key == 's':
        canvas.move(PaddleOne,0,10)

def distance(target1,target2):
    target1coords = canvas.coords(target1)
    target2coords = canvas.coords(target2)
    x1 = (target1coords[0] + target1coords[2] ) / 2
    y1 = (target1coords[1] + target1coords[3] ) / 2
    x2 = (target2coords[0] + target2coords[2])  / 2
    y2 = (target2coords[1] + target2coords[3]) / 2
    d = sqrt( (x2-x1)** 2 + (y2-y1)** 2)
    return d

def checkCollisions():
    global sideX
    global sideY
    for e in PaddleList:
        if distance(PingPongBall,e) < 20:
            if e == 1:
                sideX = 1
                sideY = random.randint(0,1)
            elif e == 2:
                sideX = -1
                sideY = random.randint(0,1)
        canvas.move(PingPongBall,sideX,sideY)
def moveBall():
    ##Found no other way of changing these variables without global##
    global sideY
    global sideX
    for e in BallList:
        xcor = canvas.coords(e)[0]
        ycor = canvas.coords(e)[1]
        if xcor >= 400: ##Right side of screen
            if sideY == -1:
                sideY = 1
                sideX = 1
            elif sideY == 1:
                sideY = -1
                sideX = -1
            elif sideX == 1:
                sideX = -1
        if xcor <= 0: ##Left side of screen
            if sideY == -1:
                sideY = 1
                sideX = 1
            elif sideY == 1:
                sideY = -1
                sideX = -1
            elif sideX == -1:
                sideX = 1
        if ycor >= 400: ##Top of screen
            if sideY == -1:
                sideY = 1
            elif sideY == 1:
                sideY = -1
        if ycor <= 0: ##Bottom of screen
            if sideY == -1:
                sideY = 1
            elif sideY == 1:
                sideY = -1
##SET UP TIMER AKA INFINITE LOOP WITHOUT LAG##
timeLeft = 1
##PADDLES AND OTHER STUFF##       
PaddleOne = canvas.create_rectangle(10 ,150 ,25 ,250 ,fill='blue')
PaddleTwo = canvas.create_rectangle(400,150 ,385 ,250 ,fill='blue')
PingPongBall = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 210 ,210 ,fill='red')
PaddleList = [PaddleOne,PaddleTwo]
BallList = [PingPongBall]
Target = PaddleList[0]
##KEY BINDINGS##
canvas.bind_all('<Key>',movePaddles)
##INFINITE LOOP##
while timeLeft > 0:
    checkCollisions()
    moveBall()
    window.update()
```

Comment: COnsider not using ```from package import *``` Best to import what you need from each package like ```from package import class```

Comment: @JasTonAChair Thank you I did that for the Square Root thing

Comment: @JasTonAChair: wildcard imports such as `from package import *` iare explicitly discouraged in PEP8, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider this control structure:

```
if xcor >= 400: ##Right side of screen
    if sideY == -1:
        sideY = 1
        sideX = 1
    elif sideY == 1:
        sideY = -1
        sideX = -1
    elif sideX == 1:
        sideX = -1
```

so lets walk through the possible scenarios:

The ball hits the right wall while going up (sideY == -1)

1. sideY is -1 so set sideY to 1 and sideX to 1
2. moves one pixel to right (further into wall) and one pixel down
3. sideY is now 1 so set sideY to -1 and sideX to -1
4. moves one pixel to left (still in wall) and one pixel up
5. go back to step 1. since `xcor>=400` is still True.

This will account for your glitchy behaviour, it is overridden when the ball touches the paddle (I will explain hitbox in a moment) but really your conditionals should just be something like this:

```
    if xcor >= 400: ##Right side of screen
        #make it go left
        sideX = -1
    if xcor <= 0: ##Left side of screen
        #make it go right
        sideX = 1
    if ycor >= 400: ##Bottom of screen
        #make it go up
        sideY = -1
    if ycor <= 0: ##Top of screen
        #make it go down
        sideY = 1
```

As for your hitbox, you are just checking if the distance from the center of the Ball to the center of the paddle is less then 20:

```
if distance(PingPongBall,e) < 20:
```

This only accounts for the middle 40% or so of the paddle which is not what you want, you want to know if they are **overlapping** which can be done by using the `in` operator, the `.find_overlapping` method and the `.bbox` method (both these methods are [described here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html))

```
def is_overlapping(tag1,tag2):
    return tag1 in canvas.find_overlapping(*canvas.bbox(tag2))
```

then you can check if the paddle is touching the ball with just:

```
if is_overlapping(PingPongBall,e):
```